# ¿Cómo puedo generar un PDF con DomPDF y guardar los datos del formulario?

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Tengo un formulario el cual recoge toda la información para generar el PDF con la librería DomPDF, el documento lo puedo generar sin problema y lo guardo en una carpeta que se crea en base a los datos, lo que quiero lograr ahora es guardar los datos del PDF en mi base de datos, se puede tener un archivo intermedio el cual tenga las acciones de hacer la inserción a la BD y que posterior a eso genere el PDF o se tendría que hacer en el archivo que genera el PDF?

El ejemplo del formulario es el siguiente:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
    <form action="plantilla.php" method="post">
        <label for="nombre">nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
        <label for="apellido">apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
        <label for="telefono">telefono</label>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono">
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perdoname, si comprendo bien quiereres que con los datos de ese formulario haga dos cosas cierto?
1.- cree un documento pdf (que ya lo haces)
2.- agregue estos datos a la BD (creo es lo que preguntas)

En base a esto debes tener una tabla con los campos definidos en el formulario más un campo clave (ID) autoincremental, que sea único para cada registro, luego crear una función que haga un insert en la BD. similar a:

```
function insertBD($reg){
  require_once('conexiobd.php'); //agregue aca su archivo de conexion
   //cambie tutabla por el nombre de su tabla
   $sql="insert into tutabla ('nombre','apellido','telefono','email') value 
 ('".$reg['nombre']."','".$reg['apellido']."','".$reg['telefono']."','".$reg['email']."')";
     $result=$bd->query($sql);
}
```

Esa función la puedes llamar de forma previa a la función que genera el pdf. puedes seguir esta lógica u otra:
Función A: que recibe el POST del formulario
llama a Función C: que guarda en la BD
llama a Función B: que genera el pdf.

si quieres que el usuario escoja si guarda o no la info deberás crear una función D: que haga la pregunta al usuario y reciba su comentario.

Si tienes un mayor trozo de código de la lógica te puedo ayudar de mejor forma

Comment: esto no responde la pregunta del usuario... no genera un pdf como output.

Comment: De echo ya pude resolverlo de momento como me dijiste, creando una función que inserta los datos y llamándola desde donde genero el PDF, así ya no se rompe el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor seria tener el codigo que guarda la data en bd separado en otro archivo, ya despues lo llamas en el archivo que genera el pdf. Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta si se puede tener todo en un mismo archivo.